# Triggering a simple event with YouTube iframe API / sync event with player.getCurrentTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

This seems like a relatively easy thing, but the lack of examples on the web (and the deprecation of the JS API) has my head spinning, so here goes.  I want some code to execute when a YouTube video gets to a certain time.  You can see examples of this [here](http://dmolsen.com/youtube-player/) and [here](http://aphall.com/random/edge-video-sync/).

What I'm trying to do is far less complicated.  When the video is 3 seconds in, I want to put some text on the page.  That's it.
http://jsfiddle.net/StephanieQ/2sj9smnd/

```
 var youtubetime;
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    if(event.data==1) { // playing
        myTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
            youtubetime = Math.round(player.getCurrentTime()*10)/10;
            $("#timeHolder").text(youtubetime);
            //return youtubetime;
        }, 100);
    }
    else { // not playing
        clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
}

if( youtubetime > 3  ) {
     $("#results").text("Working!");
```

But it doesn't work.  I've tried parseFloat (which shouldn't be needed because player.getCurrentTime(); should return a number.) and that doesn't help.
I have the current time to one decimal point displayed in a div on the bottom so clearly the variable I'm using is defined and working.

Why doesn't this work? It seems so simple...

Notes: iframe API only since the YouTube's JS API is deprecated.

EDIT: setInterval holds the key to my salvation!

```
setInterval(function () {
if (youtubetime > 3) { $("#results").text("Works!"); } }, 100);
```

I'm an idiot...

Comment: I'd recommend putting your edit as an answer to your question, then marking that as accepted as it makes it clear that you were able to find a solution yourself.

Comment: @not_a_bot Ah, I didn't know I could do that.  Thank you for the suggestion :D Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per not_a_bot's suggestion, I'm going to add my edit to answer my own question since I solved it myself and maybe others can learn from this.

I'm using setInterval to check every tenth of a second (100ms) if the variable youtubetime is greater than three seconds. Without this periodic check the anonymous function does not work (otherwise the variable is only checked on page load.)

```
setInterval(function () {
if (youtubetime > 3) { $("#results").text("Works!"); } }, 100);
```

'Cause knowledge is power!